# Why I can't index a 2-d numpy.ndarray and assign new value

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I wanna index a 2d ndarray and fetch a subset of this ndarray.
Then I assign this subset ndarray with another ndarry which has the same shape with this subset ndarray.
But the original ndarray is not changed.

Here is an example.`mat` is not changed after the assignment operation.

What I want is assign a `subset of ndarray` with another `ndarray.`

```
import numpy as np
ma = np.array([1,2,3,4,5] * 5).reshape(5,5)
mask = np.array([False, True, False, True, True])
sub = np.array([[100,101, 102],
                [103, 104, 105],
                 [106,107,108]])
ma[mask][:,mask] = sub
print(ma)
```

what I expected is:

```
array([[1, 1, 3, 1, 5],
       [1, 100, 1, 101, 102],
       [1, 1, 3, 1, 5],
       [1, 103, 3, 104, 105],
       [1, 106, 3, 107, 108]])
```

But mat is not changed:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: Not yet. I have change my question.

Comment: Qestion updated

Comment: This is not right. The output you want is `array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], |1, 100, 3, 101, 102], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 103, 3, 104, 105], [1, 106, 3, 107, 108]])`. Besides, it's not very fair to completely change your questions and then downvote the answers because they don't apply anymore. I updated it

Comment: Thanks. That is the answer which could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.where(mask, 1, np.where(mask, 1, ma).T).T
```

1. `np.where(mask, 1, ma)` use mask to replace with 1 in columns
2. `np.where(mask, 1, np.where(mask, 1, ma).T)` transpose the result and repeat again to mask rows
3. `np.where(mask, 1, np.where(mask, 1, ma).T).T` Transpose back

Output

```
np.where(mask, 1, np.where(mask, 1, ma).T).T

array([[1, 1, 3, 1, 5],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 3, 1, 5],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 3, 1, 5]])
```

Comment: This way looks a little intricate

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
ma[np.ix_(mask, mask)] = sub
```